# LimitTo not working

Tags: angularjs, pagination

The AngularJS `LimitTo` filter not working in `ng-repeat`. I have created pagination and then I need to hide except first two item. The problem is, that pagination created as `track by $index`. That is `limitTo` filter not working.

Is there anyway to create pagination? I am beginner for AngularJS so anyone help me out of this issue.

```
<li ng-repeat="i in getNumber(myNumber) track by $index | limitTo: 2" ng-class="{active: $index == selected}" ng-click="select($index)">
   <button ng-click="loadFromMenu($index+1)" ng-class="pageList">
       {{$index+1}}
   </button>
</li>
```

Answer (score 11):

Please remove `track by $index` before filter and add it after filter like below.

because filter like `limitTo` `orderBy` must come before `track by $index`.

```
<li ng-repeat="i in getNumber(myNumber)  | limitTo: 2 track by $index" ng-class="{active: $index == selected}" ng-click="select($index)">
   <button ng-click="loadFromMenu($index+1)" ng-class="pageList">
       {{$index+1}}
   </button>
</li>
```

This will work :)

cheers

Comment: I need another one help, Is there thousands of records showing my pagingnation will show 10 by 10. Initially I'm showing first set that means ten index. If I next set that will show next set 11 - 20 on pagingnation. So, out limitTo showing only first 10 index. How can show next set 11 - 20

Comment: I have put that pagination functionality [here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/vijayUI/vj3pkwsn/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `track by $index` from `ng-repeat`

```
<li ng-repeat="i in getNumber(myNumber) | limitTo: 2"
</li>
```

Comment: If I removed track by $index, this page will get error. [ngRepeat:dupes]

Comment: var itemLength = 10;
$scope.start = 0;
$scope.end = itemLength;

Comment: var itemLength = 10;
$scope.start = 0;
$scope.end = itemLength;

$http({
 method:"GET",
 url:"URL",
 dataType : "json",
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
}).then(function successCallback(data) {
 $scope.offerList = data.data.offerList;
 var i, d = new Date(), fullList = $scope.offerList.length;
    
 $scope.myNumber = Math.ceil(fullList / itemLength);
    $scope.lastStart = Math.floor(fullList / itemLength)+'0';
 $scope.getNumber = function(num) {
        return new Array(num);  
    }
 
 $scope.currentItem = 1;
 $scope.selected = 0;     
});

Comment: try use this `$scope.getNumber = function(num) { 
  var array = [];
  for(var i=0; i<num;i++)
    array.push(i);
  return array;
}`